# WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Removing {appId} failed

Tags: appium-ios

I was so excited to upgrade to XCode8 trying to run tests with iOS 10 but then found out XCode8 no longer supports automation instruments. So I accepted the fact that I need to wait for Appium’s official upgrade to run tests on iOS10 .

But what happened after I downgraded to Xcode 7.3.1 really puzzled me. I kept getting this error even on the iOS8/9 devices which were ok before the XCode8 upgrade: "WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Removing {appId} failed". Why is this happening even I am now back to XCode 7.3.1? I tried everything I can think of including removing/reinstalling ideviceinstaller.

To give more info here are my Developer Settings:

> --session-override --full-reset --native-instruments-lib --default-capabilities "{\"newCommandTimeout\": \"7200\"}"

The error is related to --full-reset. However removing that from the setting is triggering another error:

```
[debug] [iOS] App is not installed. Will try to install.

[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: 
Error: Installing {path to the app} 
failed at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/node-idevice/main.js:159:6 
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:193:7) 
at emitTwo (events.js:100:13) 
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7) 
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16) 
at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:323:11) 
at emitOne (events.js:90:13) 
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7) 
at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)
```

There must be something that was not correctly reverted after the downgrade to XCode7.3.1. Looks like some residue from the removed XCode 8 that broke everything.

Anyone has a resolution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. It seems that installing Xcode 8 has put higher restriction on ideviceinstaller, the component Appium is using to install apps on iOS devices.

Try running this in the Terminal:

$sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/

Then test that ideviceinstaller can do a new install by running:
 $ideviceinstaller -u [Your device's UID] -i [Path to your debug build]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: thanks @nchinenk, I had the same problem for days but I couldn't find an answer. You saved my days.

Comment: i had a problem completely not related to this and solved with that command, now this command saved me again, this is certainly an issue to be fixed