# Cannot start Appium with IOS real device Appium 1.5.3

Tags: ios, selenium, appium, appium-ios

It worked in the past. But recently I can't start Appium with iOS real devices anymore. My environment is as follow:

- Appium 1.5.3
- XCode 7.3
- iOS 9.1

And I use selenium and io.appium as follow

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Whenever I start the test, I always get this exception when creating iOSDriver

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Removing com.project.classname failed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I googled that from iOS 10 and XCode 8 they don't support UI Automation. I still use iOS 9 and XCode 7. Does anyone have the same problem and any solutions. I am kind of stuck here. Thanks

This is log file from Appium

```
[debug] [iOS] Running ios real device reset flow

[debug] [iOS] Full reset requested. Will try to uninstall the app 'com.project.classname'.
[debug] [iOS] Creating iDevice object with udid 5571568ad437d17f705f6645d73ef78ea5e72e7b

[iOS] Could not remove 'com.project.classname' from device

[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Removing com.project.classname failed
at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/node-idevice/main.js:145:6
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:193:7)
at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)

[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 973 ms - 175
```

Comment: Can you start it in appium gui? You may find more information by looking through the log of appium gui also.

Comment: I can't either start it in Appium. The logfile was "Can not remove com.project.classname and then Appium stopped.

Comment: Might help if you put the log file here. No one can see what is going on. Could be that your app signature has changed, could be something else.

Comment: Thanks @robx, I updated the log file. This is really annoying, because I executed it on another Mac, with the same version of Appium and Xcode, and it works on that Mac. But on my Mac, it always shows this error. Don't know if I have changed something in my system accidentally

Comment: Are both mac the same OS X version?

Comment: Yes, both of them are OS Capitan

Comment: What happens when you manually uninstall it from the ios then launch it?

Comment: It still shows the same error ..., which i have no clue why

Comment: @LouisT - it feels like appium on your machine nedds to be re-installed. can you give it a try?

Comment: @Keshav: I did it already, but still the same. However, I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522679/webdriverexception-an-unknown-server-side-error-occurred-while-processing-the-c, and it fixed my problem. Everytime before I run appium, i have to execute these commands first. I don't know why exactly, but it works and I can start my Appium again

Comment: @LouisT - but it's related to xcode 8, not sure how it worked for you. anyways,  happy to hear that you are again in business :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the problem is related to libimobiledevice or device lockdown

Use that command to install it: 
brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD

also try to use this command 
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/